# Difference between "LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc" and "LRESULT WINAPI WinProc"

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm learning to create game with DirectX9, I found the differrent version of define WinProc:

```
LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

I dont know what differrent between them, what version I should use ?
Tks bro.

Comment: the only differrence is the spelling. WINAPI is more modern.

Comment: both `WINAPI` and `CALLBACK` are defined as `__stdcall` calling convention

Comment: Where did you find these definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 #define CALLBACK   __stdcall

 #define WINAPI     __stdcall
```

From the macro definition of the two, they are the same.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types):

> CALLBACK, WINAPI, and APIENTRY are all used to define functions
> with the __stdcall calling convention. Most functions in the Windows
> API are declared using WINAPI. You may wish to use CALLBACK for
> the callback functions that you implement to help identify the
> function as a callback function.

What is the Windows calling convention?

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/developing-dlls):

> The way the name is decorated depends on the language and how the
> compiler is instructed to make the function available, that is, the
> calling convention. The standard inter-process calling convention for
> Windows used by DLLs is known as the WinAPI convention. It is defined
> in Windows header files as WINAPI, which is in turn defined using the
> Win32 declarator __stdcall.

**That is to say, WINAPI, CALLBACK and _stdcall are the same on Windows platform.**

**You can use either CALLBACK or WINAPI.**

Comment: __stdcall is technically compiler specific and should not be used directly.

Comment: @hoàng công minh hi, please tell me if my answer can help you. If you have any questions, please let me know at any time.